# When total = total + term(k) is called after every loop x is somehow 1 larger. why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math, while-loop

After Sum_naturals function passes in the identity function into the summation function in "term", when total = total + term(k) is called after every loop x is somehow 1 larger. why?

```
def summation(n, term):
    total, k = 0, 1
    while k <= n:
        total, k = total + term(k), k + 1
    return total

def identity(x):
    return x

def sum_naturals(n):
    return summation(n, identity)

sum_naturals(10)
```

Comment: Hi @AJT, welcome to StackOverflow. The `identity()` function is not increasing `x`.
Please detail what is your problem in the body of your question.

Comment: Please edit the title to fit the SO recommendations: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are aware this can be done with `def sum_naturals(n):return n*(n+1)//2; sum_naturals(10)` right?

Comment: Just a reminder, when you understand the solution to your original question: This could be simplified to an arithmetic one-line expression, it's an arithmetic progression sum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Comment: @SayandipDutta beat my comment to 1min.

Comment: You pass an argument x to identity. If you pass k to identity - in your code, term(k), then x will take the value of k. Your code passes k=1,2,3,4...10 to identity, so the value of x will change too. – CDJB 16 mins ago 
1
THERE, ahh got it. its because term(k), its passing an updated k that increases by 1 with every while loop. thanks. got it.! my misunderstanding was in the k being passed into the idenity function X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identity` isn't increasing `x` with every pass. I think the confusion might stem from this line:

```
total, k = total + term(k), k + 1
```

This is equivalent to

```
total = total + term(k)
k = k + 1
```

Perhaps this makes it easier to see that we look over k, from `k=1` to `k=10`. It is `k` that is increasing each time, not `x`.

```
def summation(n, term):
    total, k = 0, 1
    while k <= n:
        total, k = total + term(k), k + 1
    return total
```

could be replaced by

```
def summation(n, term):
    total = 0
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        total = total + term(k)
    return total
```

or even

```
def summation(n, term):
    return sum(term(k) for k in range(1,n+1))
```

Comment: im not confusing that k is increasing with every pass. if you paste the code into pythontutor which im using, between steps 15 and 16, X is now 2 instead of 1. At step 13, x=1, at step 16, x is now 2. why?

Comment: You pass an argument x to `identity`. If you pass k to identity -  in your code, `term(k)`, then `x` will take the value of `k`. Your code passes `k=1,2,3,4...10` to `identity`, so the value of `x` will change too.

Comment: THERE, ahh got it. its because term(k), its passing an updated k that increases by 1 with every while loop. thanks. got it.!